# ArcGIS server manager export tool in python code

Tags: arcgis-server

In ArcGIS server manager, I am using export tool to take a backup for my site. Now I am trying to do schedule for this tool to take a backup automatically. So how I can find this tool in python code to make this schedule

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve error messages we ask that you show us them in full using text rather than a picture so that they can be searched and also read easily on all devices.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted text nicely.